# Regex pattern For alphanumerics,//,* and decimal points up to 2 points

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a text which has alphanumerics, slash (`/`), asterisk (`*`) and decimal (`.`) up to two points like `100.00` but not `100.000`.

I have tried `[0-9A-Za-z/.*]` I have Just kept `(.*)` which is accepting everything. but it shouldn't be like that. It should be something like (./d{2}) for accepting only 2 digits after decimal(.)

Example of what I want to match:

```
GHJ1234*BVC/100.00
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have already written attempting this.

Comment: Please edit your question and put your attempt there. Not in comments.

Comment: Can you give an example line of the text you want to match?

Comment: GHJ1234*BVC/100.00

Comment: @Sairam please put that in the question, as well as what part you want to match, as well as some of the context the line is in (so we know what not to match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches the string you provided in the comments:

```
\w+\*\w+/\d+\.\d{2}
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/zT7dJ7/1)

---

Make sure when you put it in your Java code to escape all the backslashes:

```
 \\w+\\*\\w+/\\d+\\.\\d{2}
```